# How do I sort my actual deck in the deckbuilder?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

When I build a deck in the deckbuilder, I can filter and sort my cardpool at the top, but not my actual deck, which always ends up sorted by colour and then by mana-curve.

Ideally, I'd like it sorted purely by mana-curve, so I can see how it'll curve out; is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, this doesn't appear to be possible; the Filters section only affects your card pool, and the Stats section covers your existing deck.

In the stats section, though, there is an indication of the total mana curve of your deck, so this will at least give you a top-level overview of your mana curve.

In theory you could 'create' a deck containing all cards you don't want to be in your deck, so that your remaining cardpool only contains your deck; you could then filter and sort the cardpool as required. Bit of a pain, but it's the best I can think of :(